# How to fix breakpoints only updating on reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want my breakpoints to change depending on what screen size I have. for example when it's less than 768px I want there to only be 3 posters showing.

```js
this.state = {
  items: [
     {poster: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/cmx-images-prod/Item/765356/765356._SX1280_QL80_TTD_.jpg"},
     {poster: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/cmx-images-prod/Item/232863/232863._SX1280_QL80_TTD_.jpg"},
     {poster: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/cmx-images-prod/Item/779028/779028._SX1280_QL80_TTD_.jpg"},
     {poster: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/cmx-images-prod/Item/765281/765281._SX1280_QL80_TTD_.jpg"},
     {poster: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/cmx-images-prod/Item/460929/460929._SX1280_QL80_TTD_.jpg"},
     {poster: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/cmx-images-prod/Item/694446/694446._SX1280_QL80_TTD_.jpg"},
  ],
  posters: [],
  windowWith: window.innerWidth,
  splitIndex: [3,9],
}
```

```js
handleResize = (event) => {
        this.setState({ windowWith: window.innerWidth })
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.ChangeColumnSize();
        this.removeFromArr();
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize,)
      }


      componentDidUnmount() {
        this.ChangeColumnSize();
        this.removeFromArr();
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
      }

      removeFromArr() {
        let posters = this.state.items.splice(this.state.splitIndex[0],this.state.splitIndex[1])
        console.log("remove")

      }

      ChangeColumnSize() {
        if(this.state.windowWith < 768) {
            let column = this.state.splitIndex;
            column[0] = 3;
            this.setState({splitIndex: column})
        }
        else if(this.state.windowWith > 768 && this.state.windowWith < 1024) {
            let column = this.state.splitIndex;
            column[0] = 4;
            this.setState({splitIndex: column})
        } 
        else {
            let column = this.state.splitIndex;
            column[0] = 5;
            this.setState({splitIndex: column})
        }
    }
```

What's happening is that the column only get changed on page reload. Not automatically on resize.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `ChangeColumnSize()` will only be called in `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUnmount`. Try to add a functioncall inside the `handleResize` function like:

```js
handleResize = () => {
  this.setState({ windowWith: window.innerWidth });
  this.ChangeColumnSize();
}
```

And just for your information: if you're setting the state this only invokes a new run of the `render()` function.